# How do I require specific instances of a custom datatype in my XML schema?

Tags: xsd

Suppose I have a custom datatype in my schema:

```
  <xs:element name="Fruit">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Name"/>
        <xs:element ref="Supplier"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="Supplier" type="xs:string"/>
```

Elsewhere in the schema I want to require specific instances of Fruit, so I have something like the following XML file:

```
<fruits>
  <common>
    <!-- the common section should always include Fruits with these Names -->
    <Fruit>
      <Name>apple</Name>
      <Supplier>Shady Orchard</Supplier>
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit>
      <Name>orange</Name>
      <Supplier>Florida Orange Co.</Supplier>
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit>
      <Name>banana</Name>
      <Supplier>Bananaland</Supplier>
    </Fruit>
  </common>
  <exotic>
    <Fruit>
      <Name>kiwano</Name>
      <Supplier>Fancy Fruits</Supplier>
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit>
      <Name>rambutan</Name>
      <Supplier>Indonesia Fruit Co.</Supplier>
    </Fruit>
    <!-- the list goes on... -->
  </exotic>
</fruits>
```

I know I can define the exotic section in my file like this:

```
  <xs:element name="exotic">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Fruit"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

But how do I define the *common* section, such that `Fruit`s with the names *apple*, *orange*, and *banana* are always required?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to create a <common> element that only allows certain types of fruit as sub-elements and an <exotic> element that accepts all fruit. Is that right?  Or maybe you want the <common> element to actually require the three most popular fruit

Comment: Yes, it's the last thing you mentioned that I'm stuck on--I want the <common> element to require those three specific fruits.

Comment: Don't think you can do that in an xsd, certainly I cant think of a way of defining that. Schematron could validate for that, other than that you need apple orange and banana to be elements of type fruit, and then you could do it with sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard to work around. I'm pretty sure there's a more elegant solution but this will work. The only thing is, we don't really require specific instances but create specialized types to only match these values. I'm pretty sure there was a way to do it without type restriction by fixing values but I can't remember the attribute and I don't know if it would work with an alternative of three values.

Here's an xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/FruitSchema"
xmlns:fr="http://www.example.org/FruitSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/FruitSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="fruits">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="fr:common" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="fr:exotic" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="fruit">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="fr:name" />
            <xs:element ref="fr:supplier" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="name" type="xs:NCName" />
<xs:element name="supplier" type="xs:string" />

<xs:element name="exotic">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="fr:fruit" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="common">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="fruit">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:element name="name" type="fr:CommonFruitType" />
                        <xs:element ref="fr:supplier" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="CommonFruitType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NCName">
        <xs:enumeration value="apple" />
        <xs:enumeration value="orange" />
        <xs:enumeration value="banana" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and here's an example that fails validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fruits xmlns="http://www.example.org/FruitSchema" xmlns:fr="http://www.example.org/FruitSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/FruitSchema FruitSchema.xsd">
    <common>
        <!-- the common section should always include fruits with these names -->
        <fruit>
            <name>apple</name>
            <supplier>Shady Orchard</supplier>
        </fruit>
        <fruit>
            <name>apple</name>
            <supplier>Shady Orchard</supplier>
        </fruit>
        <fruit>
            <name>orange</name>
            <supplier>Florida Orange Co.</supplier>
        </fruit>
        <fruit>
            <name>banana</name>
            <supplier>Bananaland</supplier>
        </fruit>
        <fruit>
            <name>kiwano</name>
            <supplier>Fancy fruits</supplier>
        </fruit>
    </common>
    <exotic>
        <fruit>
            <name>kiwano</name>
            <supplier>Fancy fruits</supplier>
        </fruit>
        <fruit>
            <name>rambutan</name>
            <supplier>Indonesia fruit Co.</supplier>
        </fruit>
        <!-- the list goes on... -->
    </exotic>
</fruits>
```

It only validates those fruits in `common`, which are apples, oranges or bananas, no matter what the supplier is.

Comment: Now that's nice. I'm going to remember that.